# HOW TO FIX: "The valid stable is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources"

Tags: software-installation, apt

So as I'm working on a project I type in "sudo apt-get install feh" but after I pressed enter it gave me a "The valid stable isinvalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources" now I have no clue how to fix this. I have watched lots of YouTube videos and other examples on other websites and nothing has worked so please help me.

Comment: Edit your question to include the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.